# Spring - @Named annotation use a value from property

Tags: java, spring

I am injecting bean using `@Named("consumer-bean")`:

```
@Inject
    public KafkaReconMessageProcessor(
                                      @Named("consumer-bean") final KafkaReceiver<String, String> receiver) 
   {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }
```

Here, the bean name is hard coded to consumer-bean.

I have a use case where bean name is dynamic, so it should be property driven.

In my application.yml:

```
consumer-bean: kafka.receiver.topic1
```

I want to use this name in the bean to make it property driven. Is there any way to do that?

I tried with:

```
@javax.inject.Named("${consumer-bean}")}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Use `@Qualifier` instead of `@Named` (the annotation from the spring package not the regular java package).

Answer (score 0):

change `@Named("consumer-bean")` to `@Named("${kafka.consumer.bean.name}"`
where ${kafka.consumer.bean.name} is the configuration property that holds the dynamic bean name

Comment: Tried this and getting the error below.

No qualifying bean of type 'reactor.kafka.receiver.KafkaReceiver<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Named(\"${kafka.consumer.bean.name}\")}